# Multitask on a webpage

Tags: web-applications, jquery, web

can be do the multitask on a web page?

Actually I am going to develop a website where user can do many task like store data and share between friends.

In which if he upload the music file, he can listen the music in a light box, but the problem it that while he is listening the music he can't do another work (surfing) on the site.

here is the any way by which the user can listen the musics while doing the other tasks, but I don't want to open the pop-up windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use frames (in which the content is in another frame than the music player), or make the complete website navigate using ajax (much like facebook does).

Comment: actually my site is very vast there is ten of sections and every section has more than 10 pages so how it be possible if user click on the link to open a new page without restarting the music???

Comment: Ajaxing things up might be easier than it looks, quite depending on the structure of your website. Out of my head, a quick and dirty integration, would catch all A link clicks, and perform an ajax get. It would then read the response, and strip out unnessary tags (html, body etc) and insert it into your main content tag.

Comment: thanks, but is it also be possible that the music can be run without interrupting while page is refreshed by using the f5

Comment: If that is to daunting, go for the frames solution. Almost no changes are needed there, but it is a bit "outdated". 
Or start with the frames solution, to get your site up and running, and after that sit down and design your ajax page.

Comment: The F5 thing cannot be solved (not in ajax, nor in frames). You might only warn the user by catching the BeforeUnload event.

Comment: thanks mr. Gidon, could you give me the link for that type of AJAX tutorial??

Comment: You'll need some knowledge of javascript and study jQuery or another js framework.

Comment: I have worked with jQuery-UI, AJAX using javascript but I didn't work with advance AJAX concept. can you help me ?

Comment: very basic:
$('a').live('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) { /* get your data and add it to your page */}) } );

Comment: Thanks to give me your valuable time. I will follow your guidance and I hope by which I will develop my site successfully as I want.

Answer (score 1):

You could work with [ajax](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to get your contents.
Take a look at [hypem.com](http://hypem.com) There you can listen to music and still browse the page.

Or you could just use Frames.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to make a pure AJAX site so the user never leaves the page they are on. If you wanted the music continuous and the user clicked a link, the music would stop and start from the beginning when it hit the new page. By using AJAX everything can happen in the background without leaving the page you are on.

**EDIT**

These should help you accomplish your goals:

- [AJAX with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [AJAX navigation](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/)
- [AJAX database interaction](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=262)

Comment: thanks mr Asbury, could you give me the link for that type of AJAX tutorial??